# iOS: how to add "cartoon" style animation (movie) to the slide?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a slide with text AND add some animation into it for an iPad app. See screenshot below to get an idea of what I need. I want that guy jump up and down and smile. I'm sure I'm not capable of drawing that image using Objective-C primitives myself, so I'm looking at the following options:

1. Do complete animation in 3rd-party tool (Adobe?) and then add it as single standalone file on the slide. But I do not know, what formats are supported in iOS, what are standard formats, and, at the end, how to insert that file on the slide. Can somebody clarify this please?
2. Do complete animation, and then save frames as images, and then quickly change images to give illusion of a movie.

Am I missing something? Are there any other ways? what's the best option?

Please let me know if I'm not clear enough - I will try to provide more information.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a movie file for the animation, you can find the supported video formats in the [iOS Technology Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW6), under “Media Layer > Video Technologies”.  You will need to use an `AVPlayerLayer` from the [`AVFoundation` Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1) to show the video.

If you want to use a separate image file for each frame, you can use one of the `+[UIImage animatedImage...]` methods to create an animated `UIImage`, and display it in a `UIImageView`.

If you want to use a single animated GIF for the animation, you can use this [public domain `UIImage+animatedGIF` category](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) to load the GIF into an animated `UIImage`, and display it in a `UIImageView`.